# Redux thunk - async action scope changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

Technologies: react, typescript

---

### The problem

I'm trying to write an async action creator in redux that fetches the data from the server, but the scope of the inner function that i'm returning changes and dosen't know anything

---

### Code

actions/Movie.ts

```
import MovieServer from '../../server/Movie';
import { setMovies } from './movieActions';

const fetchMovies = () => {
    console.log(MovieServer);
    return async (dispatch: any) => {
        console.log(MovieServer);
        const movies: Movie[] = await MovieServer.fetchMovies();

        dispatch(setMovies(movies));
    }
}
```

server/Movie.ts

```
import Movie from "../models/movie";
import { serverURL } from "./config";

const fetchMovies = async (): Promise<Movie[]> => {
    let movies: Movie[] = [];

    try {
        const response = await fetch(serverURL + "/api/movie", {
            method: "GET"
        });


        if (!response.ok || response.status !== 200) {
            throw new Error("bad response");
        } else {
            movies = await response.json();
        }
    } catch (err) {}

    return movies;
} 

export default { fetchMovies };
```

When I run the code, the first log output is the function decleration of `MovieServer`, the second log output is `undefined`.

so inside the inner function somethings not good and its throwing an error.

---

### What i've tried

I tried wraping the inner function in a `.bind(this)` but it throws a ts compilation error: `The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code above. Maybe there's some more code that you didn't copy/paste, or is that it?  Another thing that might help is posting some code of the `../../server/Movie.js` module

Comment: Seems fine--it's a standard closure. Something else is at play.

Comment: The problem isn't there. The code is correct. the second `console.log()` returns `undefined`??

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers but it was a problem with the server, I dont know why it effected the scope of the function but I solved it